# Optimizing a Recursive Method In PHP

Tags: php, recursion, nlp

I'm writing a text tag parser and I'm currently using this recursive method to create tags of *n* words. Is there a way that it can be done non-recursively or at least be optimized? Assume that $this->dataArray could be a very large array.

```
/**
 * A recursive function to add phrases to the tagTracker array
 * @param string $data
 * @param int $currentIndex
 * @param int $depth
 */ 
protected function compilePhrase($data, $currentIndex, $depth){
    if (!empty($data)){
        if ($depth >= $this->phraseStart){
            $this->addDataCount($data, $depth);
        }
        if ($depth < $this->phraseDepth){
            $currentIndex = $currentIndex + 1;
            //$this->dataArray is an array containing all words in the text
            $data .= ' '.$this->dataArray[$currentIndex]; 
            $depth += 1;
            $this->compilePhrase($data, $currentIndex, $depth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you can use **[tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion)** rather than call-based recursion. Some rewriting may be required but a cursory looks says it is fine to do.

Tail recursion is great for a subset of recursive functions, and good practice to spot when loops can replace recursion, and how to rewrite.

Saying that, I don't know what the overhead inside PHP is of the call. Might just be one return-pointer type setup rather than a real stack wind.

> Turns out about the same. Does PHP optimize tail recursive calls out itself?

Here is my rewrite, but beware, my brain is currently sleep deprived!

```
protected function compilePhrase($data, $currentIndex, $depth){
    /* Loop until break condition */
    while(true) {
        if (!empty($data)){
            if ($depth >= $this->phraseStart){
                $this->addDataCount($data, $depth);
            }
            if ($depth < $this->phraseDepth){
                $currentIndex = $currentIndex + 1;
                // A test here might be better than the !empty($data)
                // in the IF condition. Check array bounds, assuming
                // array is not threaded or anything
                $data .= ' '.$this->dataArray[$currentIndex]; 
                $depth += 1;
            }else{
               break;
            }
        }else{
           break;
        }
    }
    /* Finish up here */
    return($this->dataArray);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It works if you add an else/break for the second nested if statement. However, it seems to average about the same speed as the recursive function.

Comment: Tail recursion isn't generally considered a speed optimization (though unwinding the stack does take time, it should be small compared to all of the string concatenation that's going on). It's a space optimization to prevent you from overflowing the stack.

Comment: @Ken How would you speed up the string concatenation?

Comment: @Ken - Good point. Though I didn't answer from a speed perspective ;)